# How can I configure the port number of a created/existing domain in weblogic to run on a different port?

Tags: dns, weblogic, port, subdomain

I dont want to create a new domain, instead I want to run it on a different in weblogic.How can I configure that?

Answer (score 1):

Open the WebLogic console, click Environment / Servers / [Server Name]. Under the Configuration tab, click General. Change the Listen Port field to the desired port number and restart WebLogic.